# Question on this Rambam

Tags: rambam, arayot

> "If, by contrast, a Jewish male enters into relations with a gentile
> woman, when he does so intentionally, she should be executed. She is
> executed because she caused a Jew to be involved in an unseemly
> transgression, as [is the law with regard to] an animal. [This applies
> regardless of] whether the gentile women was a minor of three years of
> age, or an adult, whether she was single or married. And it applies
> even if [the Jew] was a minor of nine years old, [she is executed].
>
> This [punishment] is explicitly mentioned in the Torah, as [Numbers
> 31:16-17] states: "Behold they were [involved] with the children of
> Israel according to the advice of Balaam. Execute any woman fit to
> know a man through lying with a male."

My question is if a child has not attained the age of majority, how can they be culpable for an aveirah they are unable to comprehend the gravity of?

Comment: The animal is also not capable of comprehension.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. To clarify, the other sages disagree with the Rambam.

Comment: there is a disagreement whether a gentile that is a minor transgresses one of the 7 mitzvos is punished, the Chasam Sofer says that once they understand what they're doing they are punishable. This Ramba'm might be a proof to his shita

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Chana and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @DoubleAA for the behema there is תקלה וקלון Sanhedrin 55ab for the girl I don't know if it's the case

Comment: @kouty The Rambam is clear that it is the case.

Comment: @NT can you give me the Rambam address?

Comment: Where is this Rambam?

Answer (score 2):

You're killing the girl, not as a punishment to the girl. But rather, because through her a jew  stumbled in sin. Just like you kill an animal that a jew lived with.